# Unit Display Before In Stock & After Price, multiple product Unit

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am selling fabric per yard and meters. 
$ 12/yard and $14/meter

1. multiple product Unit
   is there any way i can use two unit yard & meters
2. I want to show yard unit before "in stock" and 
   after price

i have use below method, but this is not what i need,
it will show for every product, 
some of product are selling **not** in yard unit

```
.single-product .amount:after{
    content: "yard";
    text-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you.

You need to add a custom field 'wdm_my_custom_unit' and set the unit you want eg. yard or meter for a product. And the products for which the your units don't apply do not specify any value for 'wdm_my_custom_unit' custom field while editing a product.

Write is code in your theme or a plugin.

`/* If product have a custom field my_custom_unit */`
`add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','wdm_add_unit_for_price');
function wdm_add_unit_for_price($price){
    global $post;
    $my_unit=get_post_meta( $post->ID,'wdm_my_custom_unit', true );
    if($my_unit){
       $price=$price.'/'.$my_unit;
    }
    return $price;
}`

Have tested this code and it works. Do let me know it it works for you too.

**Edit Product Page**

[image]

**Shop Page**

[image]